# Foursquare oauth_token broken sometimes?

Tags: ios, oauth, foursquare

While testing my app with the Foursquare API I am successfully using it in most of the casing. But let's say I "disconnect" the app to test failures and then "connect" again, the app (already I have a new token) tells me that this token is invalid or revoked. The only workaround of this so far is reseting the client secret.

Is this common?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I was truncating the first latter of the token when testing out callback URLs.. sorry guys :)